# SharePoint Web Part error After Reinstalling IIS Features

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, iis, web-config

Recently there was a IIS features reinstallation done on my server to resolve FBA login issues. The login is fixed now, but I am facing web part errors.

Error:

```
Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type MROWebPartCollection.InventoryWP.InventorySummary.InventorySummary, MroWebPartCollection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ebf4da56cd32d36 could not be found or it is not registered as safe. Correlation ID: ee5dc29e-5e00-a069-cd71-6d61fb5b4809.
```

This occurred to all my web parts.

I tried redeploying my `.wsp` file but to no avail.

In `web.config`, the safe control entries for my web part still exists.

May I know if the IIS features re-installation will require me to update the `PublicKeyToken` of my web parts in the web config?

Thank you.

---

**Added SafeControl from the web application web.config:**

```
  <SafeControl Assembly="MROWebPartCollection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ebf4da56cd32d36" Namespace="MROWebPartCollection.InventoryWP.InventorySummary" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

I have also tried changing `Namespace` to include extra `.SearchProduct` as per the error message. But it gave the same error as well.

---

**Namespace Differences:**

1. Web Part Properties in VS
   [image]
2. Web Part error in SP site
   [image]
3. Config file web part namespace

> SafeControl Assembly="MROWebPartCollection, Version=1.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ebf4da56cd32d36" 
>   Namespace="MROWebPartCollection.InventoryWP.InventorySummary" TypeName="*" 
>   Safe="True"

Comment: probably the SafeControl in web.config is not correct. can you copy here the SafeControl from the web application web.config where you are facing this issue?

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška added in

Comment: Try to find the assembly details and check if there is nothing different: Open the GAC. Right click on your dll and then click properties.

Comment: Have you run SP Config Wizard after re-installation IIS features.

Comment: @MarekSarad Nope, SP Config Wizard was not run after that. Does it cause an impact?

Comment: Yes it has. SPConfig ensures that right accounts have access to resources including IIS. I won't hurt to run it.

Comment: @MarekSarad I will run SP Config Wizard in awhile. I have added the webpart namespace from all 3 areas in my post. I see that my SP site error message has `InventorySummary.InventorySummary` repeated. Is it because of this? Thank you

Comment: probably not. it more looks like you were missing some web.config entries (that were added manually rather then through object code when the web part solution was deployed) do you have one or multiple front ends? If more than 1 comparing the web.config between machines could help to find the culprit missing or malformed entry.